# Firestore Database - document not returned in collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On launch my app create a document for the current user and adds it to my users collection using the following code:

```
let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("users").document(self.userId)
    .collection("MyCollection").document("aDocument")
    .setData(someData)
```

Data is created ok - [here is what it looks like in the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMzJ0.png).
The documents such as *4GhpuyGRRhXEAYCllojaaJuwZq02* are the ones created by the code above. and 'denver' is created manually when I edit the collection in the Firestore console .

Now my problem is when I want to later retrieve all the users created in my DB.
I do:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot) in
     print(snapshot?.documents.count) // prints 1
}
```

The only document returned here is denver, which is the one entered manually in the DB... 
Not sure what am I missing here. (wrong method call, auth security...?)

Answer (score 1):

Your code hasn't actually created a document with the user's UID.  Your code has created a document within a subcollection under the UID called MyCollection and a document id of "aDocument".  That's the ONLY documen created.  The UIDs you're seeing in the console are not actual documents.  They are just "phantom" placeholders that help organize your subcollections underneath them.  That's why they're displayed in italics (as opposed to denver, which is actually a document with actual fields).  Notice that when you click on one that it doesn't have any fields - that's because it's not really a document.

When you fetch all the documents under users, the only actual document you're going to get is denver, which is why the count is 1.  Everything else is not actually a document and doesn't contribute to the count.  Documents in subcollections are not fetched when you call getDocuments.  Queries in Firestore are shallow - they don't consider subcollections or the documents underneath them.

Comment: How can I do that? I want my document id to be uid of user to organize all data. How can I achieve this?